# Prove that the last digit of $4n^5-5n^2+n$ is $0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that the last digit of $4n^5-5n^2+n$ is $0$ for all natural $n$

**My attempt:**

$$4n^5-5n^2+n\overset{?}\equiv 0\pmod {10}$$

using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

$$4n\cdot\pmod 5 -5n\pmod 2+n\overset ?\equiv 0 \pmod{10}$$

I am suck here

Comment: Hint:  You just need to show that your expression is always even and always divisible by $5$.

Comment: To have last digit $0$, in base $10$, means to be divisible by $2$ and by $5$ simultaneously.

Comment: Why don't you show that the expression is divisible by both $2$ and $5$ and then conclude that since $\gcd(2,5)=1$, the expression must also be divisible by $10$ ?

Comment: @learner Why do you write: "since $gcd(2,5)=1$"?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano, Consider $4$ which is divisible by both $2$ and $4$. Does this imply that $4$ is divisible by $8$ ? For $n\mid a~\land~m\mid a\implies mn\mid a$ to hold, we need $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Comment: Worth pointing out:  it does not make sense to add a residue class $\pmod 5$ to a residue class $\pmod 2$.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano, I think he’s using the theorem that if a number is divisible by two relatively prime numbers, it is divisible by their product.

Comment: You could always use the binomial theorem and prove by induction.

Comment: Without any theorems you can do the following. Because a power of a true congruence is a true congruence, as is the sum of two (or more) congruences, you get that as a consequence of $n+10\equiv n\pmod{10}$ the result
$$4(n+10)^5-5(n+10)^2+(n+10)\equiv 4n^5-5n^2+n\pmod{10}.\qquad(*)$$
So if you can brute force verify the claim for $n=0,1,2,\ldots,9$, then $(*)$ will prove that it also holds for $n=10,11,12,\ldots,19$, and, repeating the dose, that it holds for all $n$. Of course, you can reduce your workload further by using Little Fermat (and CRT).

Comment: And, the isolated mods on the left hand side of your last equation make no sense. So please familiarize yourself with the difference between [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), and remainders of integer division (also known as *binary mod*). People with programming background often confuse the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to prove that $4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv 0\pmod {10}$.

So prove that $4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv 0\pmod {2}$, which is equivalent to $-n^2+n\equiv 0$, which is always true because $n^2\equiv n\pmod {2}$.

Then prove that $4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv 0\pmod {5}$, which is equivalent to $-n^5+n\equiv 0$, which is always true because $n^5\equiv n\pmod {5}$.

Comment: And yes, to address the comments above: combining results for 2 and results for 5 to make a result for $2\times 5$ is only possible because 2 and 5 are relatively prime.

Comment: I don't understand why $4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv 0\pmod 2$ equivalent to $-n^2+n\equiv 0$

Comment: @Error404 $4 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ and $5 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

## Proof by induction

First, show that this is true for $n=1$:

$4^5-5^2+1=1000$

Second, assume that this is true for $n$:

$4n^5-5n^2+n=10k$

Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:

$4(n+1)^5-5(n+1)^2+n+1=$

$\color\red{4n^5-5n^2+n}+20n^4+40n^3+40n^2+10n=$

$\color\red{10k}+20n^4+40n^3+40n^2+10n=$

$10(k+2n^4+4n^3+4n^2+n)$

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

---

## Proof by modular arithmetic

Consider the following cases:

- $n\equiv0\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot0^5-5\cdot0^2+0\equiv     0\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv1\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot1^5-5\cdot1^2+1\equiv   110\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv2\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot2^5-5\cdot2^2+2\equiv   930\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv3\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot3^5-5\cdot3^2+3\equiv  4020\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv4\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot4^5-5\cdot4^2+4\equiv 12380\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv5\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot5^5-5\cdot5^2+5\equiv 30930\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv6\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot6^5-5\cdot6^2+6\equiv 66990\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv7\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot7^5-5\cdot7^2+7\equiv130760\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv8\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot8^5-5\cdot8^2+8\equiv235800\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $n\equiv9\pmod{10} \implies 4n^5-5n^2+n\equiv4\cdot9^5-5\cdot9^2+9\equiv399510\equiv0\pmod{10}$

Comment: Why did you take 9 mod 10 instead of -1 mod 10?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: First of all, it's the same. Second, I thought it would be clearer to go through all options this way (i.e., from $0$ to $9$).